# Calling spotlight search from in-app

Tags: ios, spotlight

Curious to know if ios 9 allows developers to open spotlight search from their apps?

More specifically, I would like to do contacts search of the user's phone contacts using spotlight search.

So can I create a button labelled "Search in Spotlight" and have spotlight search open and search for a specific contact? It's ok if my app minimizes for spotlight search to open.